# Problem with connecting VPN (Networkmanager&Openvpn plugin) raspian RESOLVE: Cannot resolve host address

Tags: networking, dns, raspberry-pi3, openvpn, debian-buster

I have a problem with connecting to VPN. When I start up the raspberry device and connect the VPN with nmcli connection up VPN it succeceds. But if I bring the interface down and trying to bring it up again it fails. If I restart the raspberry I can connect to VPN again. What is the next step? Do you guys have any idea what has gone wrong?

In the journalctl log I get this message when it fails:

```
Could not determine IPv4/IPv6 protocol
Oct 23 15:56:24 raspberrypi nm-openvpn[2282]: SIGUSR1[soft,init_instance] received, process restarting
Oct 23 15:56:29 raspberrypi nm-openvpn[2282]: WARNING: --ns-cert-type is DEPRECATED.  Use --remote-cert-tls instead.
Oct 23 15:56:29 raspberrypi nm-openvpn[2282]: NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Oct 23 15:56:29 raspberrypi nm-openvpn[2282]: RESOLVE: Cannot resolve host address: vpn.******.**:1194 (Name or service not known)
Oct 23 15:56:29 raspberrypi nm-openvpn[2282]: RESOLVE: Cannot resolve host address: vpn.*****.**:1194 (Name or service not known).

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ openvpn --version
OpenVPN 2.4.7 arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Feb 20 2019
library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019, LZO 2.10

uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.4.51-v7+ #1333 SMP Mon Aug 10 16:45:19 BST 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux

NetworkManager --version
1.14.6
```